# How to reduce rows and increase column to achieve a new view

Tags: sql, pivot, h2

I've a table similar to this:

```
+=========+========+============+
| Session | Center | Efficiency |
+=========+========+============+
|       1 | A1     |         55 |
+---------+--------+------------+
|       1 | A2     |         66 |
+---------+--------+------------+
|       1 | A3     |         77 |
+---------+--------+------------+
|       2 | A1     |         80 |
+---------+--------+------------+
|       2 | A2     |         70 |
+---------+--------+------------+
|       2 | A3     |         60 |
+---------+--------+------------+
```

Now I'm trying to get the following results:

```
+=========+=========+=============+=========+=============+=========+=============+
| Session | Center1 | Efficiency1 | Center2 | Efficiency2 | Center3 | Efficiency3 |
+=========+=========+=============+=========+=============+=========+=============+
|       1 | A1      |          55 | A2      |          66 | A3      |          77 |
+---------+---------+-------------+---------+-------------+---------+-------------+
|       2 | A1      |          80 | A2      |          70 | A3      |          60 |
+---------+---------+-------------+---------+-------------+---------+-------------+
```

**Similarly**, when I have this table,

```
+=========+========+============+
| Session | Center | Efficiency |
+=========+========+============+
|       1 | A1     |         55 |
+---------+--------+------------+
|       1 | A2     |         66 |
+---------+--------+------------+
|       1 | A3     |         77 |
+---------+--------+------------+
|       1 | A4     |         88 |
+---------+--------+------------+
|       2 | A1     |         80 |
+---------+--------+------------+
|       2 | A2     |         70 |
+---------+--------+------------+
|       2 | A3     |         60 |
+---------+--------+------------+
|       2 | A4     |         50 |
+---------+--------+------------+
|       3 | A1     |         56 |
+---------+--------+------------+
|       3 | A2     |         67 |
+---------+--------+------------+
|       3 | A3     |         78 |
+---------+--------+------------+
|       3 | A4     |         89 |
+---------+--------+------------+
```

My output should be like this:

```
+=========+=========+=============+=========+=============+=========+=============+=========+=============+
| Session | Center1 | Efficiency1 | Center2 | Efficiency2 | Center3 | Efficiency3 | Center4 | Efficiency4 |
+=========+=========+=============+=========+=============+=========+=============+=========+=============+
|       1 | A1      |          55 | A2      |          66 | A3      |          77 | A4      |          88 |
+---------+---------+-------------+---------+-------------+---------+-------------+---------+-------------+
|       2 | A1      |          80 | A2      |          70 | A3      |          60 | A4      |          50 |
+---------+---------+-------------+---------+-------------+---------+-------------+---------+-------------+
|       3 | A1      |          56 | A2      |          67 | A3      |          78 | A4      |          89 |
+---------+---------+-------------+---------+-------------+---------+-------------+---------+-------------+
```

To get this I **tried** this one,

```
SELECT 
a.session as session, a.center as center1, a. Efficiency as Efficiency1, 
b.center as center2, b.Efficiency as Efficiency2 from
mytable a
JOIN
mytable b
on a.session=b.session AND a.center != b.center
```

But it **doesn't** show the result that I'm trying to get. It shows even many rows than before, I can't filtering out rows correctly. Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a predicatable list of `center`s, or this has to be dynamic?

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Right now I've 4 centers, later it may change. @GMB

Comment: This is the website to insert DB tables: https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a predictable, fixed list of `center`s, you can do conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    session,
    'A1' Center1,
    max(case when center = 'A1' then efficiency end) Efficiency1,
    'A2' Center2,
    max(case when center = 'A2' then efficiency end) Efficiency2,
    'A3' Center3,
    max(case when center = 'A3' then efficiency end) Efficiency3
    -- more columns if needed...
from mytable
group by session
```

Comment: I'm getting syntax error. I'm working on h2 database.@GMB

Comment: @ManojBanik: just fixed a few typos (missing `end` keyword in the `case` expressions), would you please give it another try?

Comment: I did and it works now. Thanks a lot. Is there any other option, for learning purpose.

Comment: @ManojBanik: other options would be (1) use a series of left joins (see the other answer) (2) use dynamic SQL (this is much more complicated though)

Comment: Complicated is not a problem, I want to learn if it works. Answer 2 doesn't work so far. @GMB.

Comment: What does ' max ' is doing here, Please.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this:

```
select distinct T.session,A1.*,A2.*,A3.*,A4.* from mytable as T
left outer join mytable AS A1 on A1.session=T.sessionand A1.center='A1'
left outer join mytable AS A2 on A2.session=T.sessionand A2.center='A2'
left outer join mytable AS A3 on A3.session=T.sessionand A3.center='A3'
left outer join mytable AS A4 on A4.session=T.sessionand A4.center='A4'
```

UPDATE

```
select distinct T.session,
    A1.center as Center1,A1.Efficiency as Efficiency1,
    A2.center as Center2,A2.Efficiency as Efficiency2,
    A3.center as Center3,A3.Efficiency as Efficiency3,
    A4.center as Center4,A4.Efficiency as Efficiency4
...
```

Comment: It doesn't work, getting this error message. "Column "A1.CENTER" not found;" I replaced all necessary stuffs though.

Comment: @ManojBanik why would it say this?

Comment: I apologize, it was my mistake. It works just now, but I'm getting more columns as session, I want only one column as session. Thank you so much.

Comment: It doesn't work, but I added a new part that works but couldn't show the center name properly.

Answer (score 1):

For readers using different DBMSs or if h2 ever implements `PIVOT`, here's a simplified solution:

This is the syntax for SQL Server

```
SELECT * FROM myTable PIVOT (MAX(efficiency) FOR center In (A1, A2, A3, A4)) as T
-- MAX is needed since PIVOT works with aggregate functions, but it should be MAX of a single value.
```

Resulting in:

```
+---------+----+----+----+----+
| session | A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 |
+---------+----+----+----+----+
|       1 | 55 | 66 | 77 | 88 |
|       2 | 80 | 70 | 60 | 50 |
|       3 | 56 | 67 | 78 | 89 |
+---------+----+----+----+----+
```

And if you want you could make the query dynamic and generate the list of `center` columns `(A1, A2, A3, A4)`.

---

To achieve a similar thing for h2 you can use this:

```
SELECT
    session,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE center WHEN '1A' THEN efficiency END) as 'efficiency_1A', 
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE center WHEN '2A' THEN efficiency END) as 'efficiency_2A',
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE center WHEN '3A' THEN efficiency END) as 'efficiency_3A',
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE center WHEN '4A' THEN efficiency END) as 'efficiency_4A'
FROM myTable
```

Comment: So, I can use ' min ' as well instead of ' max '? @xtratic

Comment: Yes, but note that this probably doesn't work for h2

Comment: I like this tabular form, how can I achieve this in h2 please. Thanks.

Comment: @ManojBanik I've added something that might produce a similar result for h2

Comment: Could you see the updated part from me, my center names start with a digit and it creates a problem in the query.

Comment: @ManojBanik Note that you cannot start column names with a digit so `1A` is not valid as a column name, You could instead prefix all the columns with something, as I have added to my answer.

Comment: If you think this best answers your question, then perhaps mark is as the accepted answer if you like